# Why is the parseInt function not working?

Tags: javascript, string, integer, parseint

```
    let y = "10";
    parseInt(y);
    console.log(typeof y);
```

I'm not sure why, but in the console it returns string.

Comment: Try `y = parseInt(y)`

Answer (score 1):

The `parseInt` function parses a `string` type argument and returns an integer to the `number` type of specified radix(if specified).

[must read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

So you have to assign it to some variable. In your case, if you want to convert the value of `y` and want it to be of type `number` then you can assign back to `y`.

```js
let y = "10";
y = parseInt(y);
console.log(typeof y);
```